# Delete text from file older than n seconds

Tags: c#-4.0, text

**UPDATED TO INCLUDE MORE INFORMATION** and as I've changed from trying to do this in a batch script to trying in C#.

I've asked a similar question before but this one is slightly different and I can't work out how to do it with the previous answer.

I have a .txt file (a log file) which contains aircraft lat lon data created by a program.
I then use another program (a virtual ATC radar) to read the lat lon data and position the aircraft on the radar screen.

I need the radar program to read the current lat lon and that of 3 seconds behind, as this makes for a realistic aircraft position update (a radar sweep is around 2-3 seconds) and the older data is used for the aircraft tail on screen.

The radar program is started after the log file is being generated and it starts the read at the top of the log file.

If the log file is replaced or the line being read deleted at any point the radar will stop.

The log file updates every second and looks like that below.

```
[22:37:03]

LAT:LON:Some text 1

[22:37:04]

Some:LAT:LON:text 2

Some text 3:LAT:LON

[22:37:05]

Some text 4
more:LAT:LON: text

[22:37:06]

Some more text etc etc
```

I'm looking for something that would...
Find the Time now -3 seconds.
Delete anything before that time stamp.

Below is what I currently have and works well, apart from the fact that the log file grows (as I never know how many lines to skip).
If I don't skip lines the start of the log file is too old and aircraft are not where they show on the radar screen.
If I skip too many lines there is never any data to read.

```
var content = File.ReadAllText("output.txt");
File.AppendAllText("data.txt", content);
var data = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt").Skip(6);
File.WriteAllLines("data.txt", data);
```

Can I skip all lines before a time stamp -3 seconds?

Or is there another way that I haven't thought of?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you intend to modify the original log file while the originating app  is still appending to it? This might get you into a dead lock situation or loose updates.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Do you want to have a sort of tail command not with last lines but with last seconds? And what/who will use/view/interrogate this shortened log file?

Comment: What have you tried on your own so far, what do you have trouble with? Please share your efforts!

Comment: @LotPings The new data can be written to a new file, but which ever file is being read can not be replaced.
If that makes sense?
So maybe a solution that would append the new data to end and remove any old data every second would work.

Comment: @aschipfl At the moment I'm only appending the latest data from the log file to the end of a new file and skipping the first 5 lines with
for /f "skip=5 delims=" %%a in (%data%) do (
echo %%a     
) > %temp%

Comment: Edit the question to include your efforts - comments aren't for code, there already is one close vote for the question being to broad.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm fairly new to how stackoverflow works. I'll open my code now and post above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set /a targets=%time:~6,2%
set /a targetm=%time:~3,2%
if %targets% LSS 3 (
        set /a targets=targets - 3 + 60
        set /a targetm-=1
)
set /a flag=0

call > %myTemp%
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%data%) do (
        if !flag! EQU 0 (
                set line=%%a
                if "!line:~0,1!"=="[" (
                        set lineM=!line:~4,2!
                        set lineS=!line:~7,2!
                        if !lineS! GEQ !targets! ( if !lineM! GEQ !targetm! (
                                set flag=1
                        ))
                )
        ) else (echo %%a >> %myTemp%)
)
```

Something along these lines, where you get the current time minus three seconds, and loop through the data file, checking each time you come across a timestamp to see if it fits the bill, and writing everything after this.

Without more information about the log file and the program reading from data.txt, I'm afraid this is the best I can do.

P.S. I doubt this code works as is, I just wanted to give a close example.